# SQL decimal conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal

I have some problem during converting this decimal value shown below:

```
21.6080402010050
```

Can anyone help me to convert this to become `21.6`?

I have tried with this but it doesn't work.

```
(convert(decimal(10, 2), SUM(t1.TOTAL))
```

This is the query

```
SELECT 
    t1.LINE_NO, t1.E_FIELD, t1.F_FIELD, t1.G_FIELD, t1.HSA_STATUS, 
    t1.FAMILY, t1.CACHE_FAMILY, 
    SUM(t1.TOTAL) AS CountOfLineNo, t2.TotalOfLineNo, 
    (convert(decimal(8,1), SUM(t1.TOTAL)) * 100 / t2.TotalOfLineNo ) AS Percentage
FROM (
    SELECT 
        LINE_NO, E_FIELD,F_FIELD,G_FIELD,HSA_STATUS,FAMILY,CACHE_FAMILY, 
        Count(LINE_NO) as Total
    FROM TX_HSA_SUMM
    WHERE MT_TIMESTAMP2 BETWEEN ('2013-03-07 10:10:00') AND ('2013-03-08 10:20:00')
    GROUP BY LINE_NO, E_FIELD, F_FIELD, G_FIELD, HSA_STATUS, FAMILY, CACHE_FAMILY) AS t1 
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT LINE_NO, COUNT(LINE_NO) AS TotalOfLineNo
      FROM TX_HSA_SUMM
      WHERE MT_TIMESTAMP2 BETWEEN ('2013-03-07 10:10:00') AND ('2013-03-08 10:20:00')
      GROUP BY LINE_NO) AS t2 ON t1.LINE_NO = t2.LINE_NO
GROUP BY 
   t1.LINE_NO, t1.E_FIELD, t1.F_FIELD, t1.G_FIELD, t1.HSA_STATUS, t1.FAMILY, 
   t1.CACHE_FAMILY, t1.Total, t2.TotalOfLineNo
ORDER BY 
   t1.LINE_NO, t1.E_FIELD, t1.F_FIELD, t1.G_FIELD, t1.HSA_STATUS, t1.FAMILY, 
   t1.CACHE_FAMILY, t1.Total, t2.TotalOfLineNo
```

and output is

```
LINE_NO E_FIELD F_FIELD G_FIELD HSA_STATUS FAMILY CACHE_FAMILY CountOfLineNo    TotalOfLineNo   Percentage
23053B  00000   00000   00000   S   SUMMIT  WER 43  199 21.608040201005%
```

Comment: what DB engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below query

```
SELECT t1.LINE_NO, t1.E_FIELD, t1.F_FIELD, t1.G_FIELD, t1.HSA_STATUS, t1.FAMILY, t1.CACHE_FAMILY, 
    SUM(t1.TOTAL) AS CountOfLineNo, t2.TotalOfLineNo, convert(decimal(18,1),(convert(decimal(8,1),SUM(t1.TOTAL)) * 100 / t2.TotalOfLineNo)) AS Percentage
    FROM (
          SELECT LINE_NO, E_FIELD,F_FIELD,G_FIELD,HSA_STATUS,FAMILY,CACHE_FAMILY, Count(LINE_NO) as Total
          FROM TX_HSA_SUMM
          WHERE MT_TIMESTAMP2 BETWEEN ('2013-03-07 10:10:00') AND ('2013-03-08 10:20:00')
          GROUP BY LINE_NO,E_FIELD,F_FIELD,G_FIELD,HSA_STATUS,FAMILY,CACHE_FAMILY
        ) AS t1 
    LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT LINE_NO, COUNT(LINE_NO) AS TotalOfLineNo
          FROM TX_HSA_SUMM
          WHERE MT_TIMESTAMP2 BETWEEN ('2013-03-07 10:10:00') AND ('2013-03-08 10:20:00')
          GROUP BY LINE_NO
          ) AS t2 
      ON t1.LINE_NO = t2.LINE_NO
    GROUP BY t1.LINE_NO, t1.E_FIELD, t1.F_FIELD, t1.G_FIELD, t1.HSA_STATUS, t1.FAMILY, t1.CACHE_FAMILY, t1.Total,t2.TotalOfLineNo
    ORDER BY t1.LINE_NO, t1.E_FIELD, t1.F_FIELD, t1.G_FIELD, t1.HSA_STATUS, t1.FAMILY, t1.CACHE_FAMILY, t1.Total,t2.TotalOfLineNo
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT ROUND(21.6080402010050,1)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11412)

It should work with most RDBMS.

With your edits:

```
ROUND((convert(decimal(8,1),SUM(t1.TOTAL)) * 100 / t2.TotalOfLineNo ),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175003.aspx)** function

```
select round(21.6080402010050,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `ROUND` function.

```
select round(21.6080402010050, 1)
```

Will work on MS SQL Server or MySQL

Comment: i have tried that as well. since there is actually quite number of rows. the above is the output after some select query execute

Comment: It doesn't matter how many rows are being returned.  Does the following work?  `round((convert(decimal(8,1),SUM(t1.TOTAL)) * 100 / t2.TotalOfLineNo ), 1) AS Percentage`